# How to Digitally sign xml file in Android

Tags: android

I have xml file that I should send along with HttpRequest to the URL.
Before sending it to the server,I need to digitally sign the xml file with password for security purpose.After signing,I need the output in the form of xml with signature tags.
I want to know how to implement this in android.
To do xml digital signing,we need following libraries:
javax.xml.crypto,javax.xml.crypto.dsig,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec,javax.xml.crypto.dom,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom

How to import these libraries in android?.I tried adding xmlsec.jar to build path but i'm getting runtime issues(Class not found Exception,java.lang.verify error like that)

Or is there any other way to do xml signing in android?
Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's the specification. http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/   XML Signatures are just tags in the file.  What do you mean "how to implement this in Android"?  How to encrypt the signature or how to add tags to the XML?

Comment: How to sign the input xml file and get output in xml with signature tags added to the input xml file?There is no direct support for this in Android.How to actually add support for this in android?Sorry If I'm still not clear.

Comment: Please give me some suggestions.I'm waiting for the reply.